# active directory filter with objectGUID encoded as specified in rfc2254 doesn't work

Tags: active-directory, ldap, jndi, spring-ldap, active-directory-group

I'm using java ldap to access active directory, more specifically spring ldap.
a group search by objectGUID yields no results when the filter is encoded as specified in rfc2254.

this is the guid in its hex representation:

```
\49\00\f2\58\1e\93\69\4b\ba\5f\8b\86\54\e9\d8\e9
```

spring ldap encodes the filter like that:

```
(&(objectClass=group)(objectGUID=\5c49\5c00\5cf2\5c58\5c1e\5c93\5c69\5c4b\5cba\5c5f\5c8b\5c86\5c54\5ce9\5cd8\5ce9))
```

as mentioned in [rfc2254](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2254#page-5) and in microsoft [technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx#Special):

> the character must be encoded as the backslash '' character (ASCII
> 0x5c) followed by the two hexadecimal digits representing the ASCII
> value of the encoded character. The case of the two hexadecimal
> digits is not significant.
> Blockquote

so a backslash should be '\5c'

but I get no results with above filter from AD. also if I put that filter in AD management console custom filters it does not work.
when I remove the 5c from the filter it works both from java and in AD console.

Am I missing something here?

of course I can encode the filter without the 5c but I'm nt sure it the right way and I prefer to let spring encode the filters because it knows a lot of things that I should do manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the blog entry at:[http://www.developerscrappad.com/1109/windows/active-directory/java-ldap-jndi-2-ways-of-decoding-and-using-the-objectguid-from-windows-active-directory/](https://web.archive.org/web/20180226001713/http://www.developerscrappad.com/1109/windows/active-directory/java-ldap-jndi-2-ways-of-decoding-and-using-the-objectguid-from-windows-active-directory/) provides the information you need.

Comment: Thanks. I already did find that yesterday and I bind to groups using the binding string and not the byte string, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

i found solution with php  to get user with objectGUID
etap one when i create user i put his objectGuid in bdd, the objectGuid that you see in the Ad ex $guid_str = "31207E1C-D81C-4401-8356-33FEF9C8A"
after i create my own function to transform this object id int hexadécimal

```
function guidToHex($guid_str){

$str_g= explode('-',$guid_str);

$str_g[0] = strrev($str_g[0]);
$str_g[1] = strrev($str_g[1]);
$str_g[2] = strrev($str_g[2]);

$retour = '\\';
$strrev = 0;
foreach($str_g as $str){
    for($i=0;$i < strlen($str)+2; $i++){
        if($strrev < 3)
            $retour .= strrev(substr($str,0,2)).'\\' ;
            else
                $retour .= substr($str,0,2).'\\' ;
                $str = substr($str,2);

    }
    if($strrev < 3)
        $retour .= strrev($str);
        else
            $retour  .= $str ;


            $strrev++;
}
return $retour;
```

}

this function return me a string like \1C\7E\20\31\1C\D8\01\44\83\EF\9C\8A"\F9\ED\C2\7F after this i put this string  in my filter and i get the user

#

to get  format of objectGuid 
i use this fonction that i foud it in internet

```
function convertBinToMSSQLGuid($binguid)
{
    $unpacked = unpack('Va/v2b/n2c/Nd', $binguid);
    return sprintf('%08X-%04X-%04X-%04X-%04X%08X', $unpacked['a'], $unpacked['b1'], $unpacked['b2'], $unpacked['c1'], $unpacked['c2'], $unpacked['d']);
}
```

i mean this format = 31207E1C-D81C-4401-8356-33FEF9C8A

Comment: i'am happy that this help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Pass a byte array and search should work.