# How to convert Active Directory objectGUID to UUID in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, active-directory, uuid

I have a CFLDAP query returning the objectGUID. How can I convert this to a valid UUID string in a 8-4-4-4-12 pattern in ColdFusion?

I have specified `returnAsBinary="ObjectGUID"`, but `toString(getLDAP.ObjectGUID)` does not return the desired result.

**Update:**

I tried binaryEncode():

```
<cfset guid = binaryencode(getLDAP.objectguid,"HEX")>
```

Which returns:

```
18E0CE3388B79C4EA4D73894AE8CD8F6
```

But I'm expecting this (was extracted and supplied by another process that I cant see their conversion steps).

```
3cee018-b788-4e9c-a4d7-3894ae8cd8f6
```

Hummm... Although they don't match, the last half is the same. `a4d7-3894ae8cd8f6`.

Comment: Are you pulling it from a SQL query? You can try `CAST(objectGUID AS uniqueidentifier)` in your query. That may work.

Comment: **Edit** "does not return the desired result." What does it return? If it's binary, did you try binaryencode()? That should get you closer. IF it's the same length, may still have to do some substring manipulation to get the dashes in the right places.

Comment: <cfset guid = binaryencode(getLDAP.objectguid,"HEX")> returns: 18E0CE3388B79C4EA4D73894AE8CD8F6 
but I'm expecting: 3cee018-b788-4e9c-a4d7-3894ae8cd8f6 (this was extracted and supplied by another process that I cant see their conversion steps).

Comment: hummm... the last half is the same. a4d7-3894ae8cd8f6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> hummm... the last half is the same

Interesting.  A link from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14956687/8895292) explains why.  Apparently, it is [more involved than just converting the binary into hex, in one shot](http://www.developerscrappad.com/1109/windows/active-directory/java-ldap-jndi-2-ways-of-decoding-and-using-the-objectguid-from-windows-active-directory/):

> 1. First, know the sequence of the byte index that forms the Dashed String:
>      `[3] [2] [1] [0] - [5] [4] - [7] [6] - [8] [9] - [10] [11] [12] [13] [14] [15]`
> 2. Next, apply bit masking to each and every single byte value accessed in the array.
> 3. Follow by converting to the Hex representation of the value.
> 4. Just make sure that the Hex value is a double digit value, meaning instead of "A", it should be "0A"

Since CF's arrays are 1-based, just add +1 to the positions. This builds the decoded string in the proper sequence (sans dashes, which you can easily add with string functions).

```
 // Get GUID binary
 bin = yourQuery.objectGUID[rowNumber];
 // Extract bytes in this sequence
 order = [4,3,2,1, 6,5, 8,7, 9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16];
 // Stores converted bytes
 hex = [];

 for (pos in order) {
    // Apply mask to current byte and convert to hext 
    arrayAppend(hex, formatBaseN(BitAnd(bin[pos], 255), 16));
 }

 writeOutput("Hex string = "& arrayToList(hex, ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes... I found this in an old CF post and it worked for me:

```
<CFLDAP ACTION="query" NAME="getLDAP" START="DC=info,DC=sys" SCOPE="subtree" STARTROW="1" maxRows="1"
SERVER="#domainCONTROLLER#" USERNAME="#USERNAME#" PASSWORD="#PASSWORD#" PORT="389" TIMEOUT="60"
ATTRIBUTES="sAMAccountName,mail,name,givenName,middleName,sn,title,department,ObjectGUID"
FILTER="sAMAccountName=#session.username#"
returnAsBinary = "ObjectGUID">

<cfset hexguid = BinaryEncode(getLDAP.objectguid,"Hex")>
<cfset sthex = toString(hexguid)>

<cfset GuidStr = mid(sthex,7,2)>
<cfset GuidStr = GuidStr & mid(sthex,5,2)>
<cfset GuidStr = GuidStr & mid(sthex,3,2)>
<cfset GuidStr = GuidStr & mid(sthex,1,2)>
<cfset GuidStr = GuidStr & mid(sthex,11,2)>
<cfset GuidStr = GuidStr & mid(sthex,9,2)>
<cfset GuidStr = GuidStr & mid(sthex,15,2)>
<cfset GuidStr = GuidStr & mid(sthex,13,2)>
<cfset GuidStr = GuidStr & mid(sthex,17,18)>
<cfset guid = left(GuidStr,8) & "-" & mid(GuidStr,9,4) & "-" & mid(GuidStr,13,4) & "-" & mid(GuidStr,17,4) & "-" & mid(GuidStr,21,18)>
```

Yours is more eloquent. Thanks!

Comment: That works too :) Thanks for  posting another option.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a javascript implementation I did for a Pentaho Kettle "Modified Javascript" step.

It receives the `objectGUID` from Java as byte[16] array, and continues to use Java classes for processing.

```
var b = objectGUID; // JavaArray

// the byte order is: [3] [2] [1] [0] - [5] [4] - [7] [6] - [8] [9] - [10] [11] [12] [13] [14] [15]
var theByteOrder = [3,2,1,0,5,4,7,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]; 

var ordered = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream(16);
theByteOrder.forEach(function(i) {
    ordered.write(b[i]); 
});

var bb = java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(ordered.toByteArray());
bb.order(java.nio.ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
var uuid = new java.util.UUID(bb.getLong(), bb.getLong());

var GUID = uuid.toString();
```

it's not coldfusion dialect, yes, but hopefully it will be useful for somebody scanning the web to solve a similar task.