# Active Directory, PHP's ldap_search and objectGUID

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap, uuid, guid

I have managed to decode the `objectGUID` that an Active Directory server sends me in order to create a UUID string (`xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx`). But it seems that I'm not able to reliably covert it back to perform a search using `ldap_search`.

Sometimes the search works, sometimes it fails with an `ldap_search(): Search: Bad search filter` error. If it helps, this uuid works (`1a5313e5-d8e4-42b4-b3a0-6bd96bd86e75`) and those don't (`3222a300-0beb-4650-a37d-f75bec68959c`, `833d21dc-8229-47ec-98c0-792b81f92206`).

Here is what I have now:

```
/**
 * This always manages to convert the GUID into a valid UUID
 */
function objectGuidToUuidString(string $objectGuid): string
{
  $unpacked = array_map('dechex', unpack('V_a/v2_b/n4_c', $objectGuid));
  $unpacked['_a'] = str_pad($unpacked['_a'], 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
  $unpacked['_b1'] = str_pad($unpacked['_b1'], 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
  $unpacked['_b2'] = str_pad($unpacked['_b2'], 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
  $unpacked['_c1'] = str_pad($unpacked['_c1'], 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
  $unpacked['_c2'] = str_pad($unpacked['_c2'], 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
  $unpacked['_c3'] = str_pad($unpacked['_c3'], 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
  $unpacked['_c4'] = str_pad($unpacked['_c4'], 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
  return "{$unpacked['_a']}-{$unpacked['_b1']}-{$unpacked['_b2']}-{$unpacked['_c1']}-{$unpacked['_c2']}{$unpacked['_c3']}{$unpacked['_c4']}";
}

/**
 * This don't always work.
 */
function uuidStringToObjectGuid(string $uuidString): string
{
  $uuidString = str_replace('-', '', $uuidString);

  $pieces = [
    ltrim(substr($uuidString, 0, 8), '0'),
    ltrim(substr($uuidString, 8, 4), '0'),
    ltrim(substr($uuidString, 12, 4), '0'),
    ltrim(substr($uuidString, 16, 4), '0'),
    ltrim(substr($uuidString, 20, 4), '0'),
    ltrim(substr($uuidString, 24, 4), '0'),
    ltrim(substr($uuidString, 28, 4), '0'),
  ];

  $pieces = array_map('hexdec', $pieces);
  return pack('Vv2n4', ...$pieces);
}

function doSearch(string $uuidString)
{
  $guidString = uuidStringToObjectGuid($uuidString);
  $searchResult = ldap_search($boundConnection, $baseDn, "(objectguid=$guidString)");
  [...]
}
```

Comment: If you were to take one of the `$guidstring` values can you test using that string directly in AD? (either using Users&Computers query or cmd line)

Comment: I'm not sure if I can because the string outputted by `uuidStringToObjectGuid` is binary gibberish, I'm not even sure that if I ctrl+C it I would get "all" the string to paste :/

Comment: ok - so there is no easy way to know if the conversion functions are doing exactly what they are supposed to

Comment: Don't know if [this is relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935832/active-directory-filter-with-objectguid-encoded-as-specified-in-rfc2254-doesnt) or [perhaps this](https://serverfault.com/questions/140683/get-an-object-by-its-objectguid-using-ldapsearch)?

Comment: I've seen this encoding, but 1) I'm not sure on the order of the bytes to send (can figure out tho) and 2) why some uuid encoded by my method work then? There should be something else here...

Comment: sadly I have no easy way to test this - my Active Directory server setup is packed away and I'm too busy/lazy to build a VM with AD on.